# import whole files in the Directory

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, head

I need to import whole css files available in a specific folder (css)
Is there a method to do it without importing file by file?

need to import **assets/css/*** ?

```
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/*" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <style>
            #area {
                max-width: 600px;
            }
        </style>


</head>
```

Comment: You can try `glob()` => http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** Late answer it seems and you have accepted an answer. Had I known, I would not have submitted this. I was busy testing and formulating it.

As I stated in a comment, you can use PHP's [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function to achieve this, along with a `foreach` loop. Here is what you can do:

```
foreach (glob("*.css") as $css) {
    echo "<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"$css\">\n";
}
```

Which in HTML source will produce something similar to:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css_1.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css_2.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css_3.css">
```

Depending on where your files are located, you may need to change the path to those files.

I.e.:

```
foreach (glob("path/to/css/folder/*.css")
```

---

Placing the PHP for it inside `<head></head>`

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

<?php 

    foreach (glob("*.css") as $css) {
        echo "<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"$css\">\n";
    }

?>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="css_1">Style 1</div>
    <br>
    <div id="css_2">Style 2</div>
    <br>
    <div id="css_3">Style 3</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is what I was try to find. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way you can import `css` files from a folder by doing `assets/css/*`. But you can concatenate files from css folder into one file and then minify this css file and import it.

You can use build tools like `gulp` to accomplish this thing. Check this out https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-css

Answer (score 1):

No. For one thing, the client would have no idea what to request (it can request only one file per http request, whose name it needs to know). You can do it in four ways:

- Concatenate all of your CSS files into one file, then link to that file.
- Have a script that will concatenate all CSS files into one response, then link to that script
- Have a loop in your template going over all the CSS files, which will issue one `<link>` element per file.
- If you only have several CSS files than do not change, you can just write them all out by hand.